# How to ocr text with white foreground using openCV and python tesseract

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

1st would like to thanks for taking look over here.

Im trying to read text from image and using opencv and pytesserect lib.

code

```
cv2.waitKey(1000)
img = cv2.imread("Receipt/12.jpeg")
img_ = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('temp',imgGray)
dd= pytesseract.image_to_data(imgGray)
print(dd)
ddd= pytesseract.image_to_string(imgGray)
print(1111)
print(ddd)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It's detecting text perfectly but if the text is with white/or other foreground, its not detecting text

Any help appriciable[image]ble

Comment: Threshold on the purple color using cv2.inRange(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981. Then search this forum or Google for examples.

Comment: @frmW42 : thanks for your time.
Is it possible to you for share algo to read above background text using pytesserect

Comment: Sorry, I have never used pytesseract.

Comment: PyTesseract works best with black text on white background. Maybe you can do one pass on image binarized to black text on white then invert to get the text that is white text on black?